# Meaning of "take a stab at doing something"

Tags: meaning

I was wondering what "take a stab at doing something" means? For example

> I'll take a stab at answering these.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_a_stab_at

Comment: @RegDwigнt Still, I like to read more descriptive answers from the community: as you see you get *many more* human-hints on the meaning of the sentence than a systematic dictionary definition (see *chaos* answer). So: I *un*-endorse the decision to close this question, :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As everybody has said, *to take a stab at* means *to attempt*.  I want to additionally note here that I believe it to be related to the idiom *stab in the dark*, meaning an attempt at something with little guidance or hope of success.  It doesn't carry the full weight of that meaning, though, just an attenuated implication of not necessarily knowing what one is doing, more likely used as mild self-deprecating humor than anything else.

Answer (score 4):

It is simply an informal way of saying "make an attempt".

The following are all equivalent answers to the question of "Do you want to do (something)?"

> Sure, I'll take a stab at it.
>
> Sure, I'll give it a try.
>
> Sure, I'll have a go at it.

Comment: Thanks! How is stab related to attempt?

Comment: My google-fu comes up with very inconclusive results, in fact only one place even tries to provide any etymology.  However, its vague idea agrees with my own, so:  it's sort of a hunting analogy, you're "taking a stab" at something to see if you can hit a vital point, or strike at the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 3):

*Stab at* means *attempting to do something*.

The NOAD report the following example:

> Meredith made a feeble stab at joining in.